# Was any reason given for Anne Willoughby's foreign accent in "Three Billboards Outside Ebbing, Missouri"?

Tags: character, three-billboards-outside-ebbing

In "*Three Billboards Outside Ebbing, Missouri*", William Willoughby's wife Anne speaks with an obviously foreign accent, and foreign to North America, not just to Missouri.

Was any explanation of her origins (and how she ended up in Ebbing) ever given in the film?

Answer (score 3):

She speaks with an Australian accent. The actress who played her is Australian. There is no information about why she came to the US or how he met her husband.